# Generate test cases for red black tree

Tags: testing, functional-testing

How do I generate test cases for my red-black tree implementation in C?

Comment: your question could be more specific. It depends on how you implemented it. Theoretically there's no specific unit test for a given code

Comment: I can add the code but it'll take some space :D

Comment: @iberbeu I'm thinking of inserting lots of values (lika a million) and compute the height of the tree.

Comment: The point here is that you are not talking about unit-testing but functional testing.

Answer (score 5):

The tests cases are specific to your implementation
but I think a good trick for learning would be to  try random insertion and deletion then display your tree using Gui or console printing in debugging mode.(Be careful use good debugger).
To check if your answer is correct try the visualisation from this website
https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/RedBlack.html